Concise way to express $\sum_{A\subset(1,2,3,...,n)}\left(\prod_{i\in A}k_i\prod_{(i,j)\subset A}k_{i,j}\right)$, and another
I wonder if there might be a better way to express $E_n$ and $F_n$ where:
$$E_n=\sum_{A\subset(1,2,3,...,n)}{\left(\prod_{i\in A}k_i\prod_{(i,j)\subset A}k_{i,j}\right)}$$
$$E_1=1+k_1$$
$$E_2=1+k_1+k_2+k_1k_2k_{1,2}$$
$$E_3=1+k_1+k_2+k_3+k_1k_2k_{1,2}+k_2k_3k_{2,3}+k_3k_1k_{3,1}+k_1k_2k_3k_{1,2}k_{2,3}k_{3,1}$$
$$\vdots$$
and
$$F_n=\sum_{A\subset(1,2,3,...,n)}{\left(|A|\prod_{i\in A}k_i\prod_{(i,j)\subset A}k_{i,j}\right)}$$
$$F_1=1 k_1$$
$$F_2=1 k_1+1 k_2+2 k_1k_2k_{1,2}$$
$$F_3=1 k_1+1 k_2+1 k_3+2k_1k_2k_{1,2}+2k_2k_3k_{2,3}+2k_3k_1k_{3,1}+3k_1k_2k_3k_{1,2}k_{2,3}k_{3,1}$$
$$\vdots$$
Here, $k_{i,j}=k_{j,i}$ and all $k_i$ and $k_{i,j}$ are bigger than 0. Therefore we have $2^n$ terms in $E_n$ and $2^n-1$ terms in $F_n$.
I encountered these expressions while I was dealing with some chemical kinetics, and I would like to play with them with less $\sum$ or $\prod$.
You can use anything if it makes it look simpler: factorization, calculus or linear algebra. It would be better if there is some notation for these expressions. I would be grateful too if there are better tags for this question.

I don't think without assumptions (e.g. some $k_i$ or $k_{i,j}$ are equal) it is nearly impossible to simplify them... It may be helpful if you can prove that this expression is not being able to be factorized.

What I came up with was using matrices.
$E_n=\sum_{\mathbf i \subset (1, 2, 3,\cdots,n)}{\exp(\mathbf1_n((\mathbf a_n^T \mathbf a_n )\odot \mathbf K _n )\pmb 1_n^T )}$
where:
$\mathbf 1_n=(1, 1, 1, \cdots, 1) \qquad : (1\times n )$
$\mathbf a_n = (a_1, a_2, a_3, ..., a_n) \qquad :(1\times n)$
where $a_i=1$ if $i\in \mathbf i$ else $0$
$\odot$ is Hadamard product (element-wise product)
$\mathbf K_n= \begin{bmatrix}
\ln k_{1} & 0.5\ln k_{12} & \cdots & 0.5\ln k_{1n} \\
0.5\ln k_{12} & \ln k_2 & \cdots & 0.5\ln k_{2n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0.5\ln k_{1n} & 0.5\ln k_{2n} & \cdots & \ln k_n\\
\end{bmatrix} \qquad: (n\times n)$
I needed to define some vectors and matrices, but at least this made it much easier to apply calculus.
And the second expression could be related to the first expression:
$F_n=\sum_{k = k_i, k_{ij}} k \frac{\partial E_n}{\partial k}$
